# Is this a b43 driver problem?

Tags: wireless, networking, dell, b43

I have 13.04 on a Dell Inspiron 1564 with Broadcom 4312 WiFi card. The [wl drivers cause kernel panic on linux-3.8](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1134389) so I succesfully installed the b43 driver a couple of months ago. Now I have changed ISP and got a new router, and the connection drop when downloading software from internet to a 2008r2 using Remmina Client, and `apt-get install` on virtual machines in virtualbox.

I have no idea why this suddenly became a problem.. My phone does not loose the connection, just Ubuntu.

[Output from /var/log/syslog after lost connection](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6355217/)

*rfkill list(after disconnecting):*

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: yes
```

I can use NetworkManager to disable wireless and then enable wireless to connect again. `rfkill ublock all/wifi/0` removes only Soft blocked.

*lshw -C network*

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 4
   logical name: wlan0
   serial: 78:e4:00:78:d2:05
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=b43 driverversion=3.8.0-32-generic firmware=478.104 ip=10.0.0.3 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE
```

*lspci*

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
```

After waking from suspend and when booting, it takes about 40 sec to get network connection. This has been a problem all along AND a different question, but I mention it anyway.. cus it's annoying!

Please take a look and hopefully someone spot a problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Saucy Salamander bcmwl-kernel-source seems to fix all my WiFi issues.

To install this driver in Ubuntu 13.04, follow these steps:

1. Download the driver module form [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.30+bdcom-0ubuntu1)
2. Open terminal and type: `cd Downloads`
3. Then type: `sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.30+bdcom-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

The b43 driver I used to avoid the kernel panics with the older bcmwl-kernel-source had several issues. The two most general issues were that it cut my WiFi speed in half, giving me speed test results of 15Mbps when I should have 30Mbps. The second issue were that it took 30-50 seconds to connect after boot or suspend.

Both issues are resolved after installing the new bcmwl-kernel-source module.

So far the new module has worked perfectly!